# Routes[] is not assignable to Routes

Tags: typescript, angular

Ошибка кажется простая, но не могу понять в чем проблема.

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';

export const REGISTER_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent
  }
];
```

//

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';
import { AuthGuard } from '../auth/auth.guard';
import { REGISTER_ROUTES } from './register/register.routes';

export const PARTNER_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {
      authority: 'ROLE_PARTNER'
    },
    children: [
      ...REGISTER_ROUTES
    ]
  }
];
```

Intellij IDEA ругается на `children: [...REGISTER_ROUTES]`

Comment: Если idea ругается по какой-то причине, но нет ошибок компиляции, то не нужно сразу бежать и задавать вопрос, а может стоит погуглить :) к тому же ты не показал даже что пишет idea...

Answer (score 0):

Вы же импортируете REGISTER_ROUTES уже в готовом виде. Не нужно его спредом разворачивать.

```
children: REGISTER_ROUTES
```

Comment: да, но ведь конструкция `[...arr]` это копия массива `arr`?

Comment: к тому же, помимо REGISTER_ROUTES я буду добавлять другие массивы. То есть в итоге хочется получить такое: `[...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3, ...]`